# Percent height of <a> element not accurate to parent <div> height

Tags: html, css

In my assignment, I've been having a lot of issues lately with height:x%; it's not accurate when used in some parts of my code, such as this:

My `<a>` element, a child of `<div>`, has a child `<img>`. `<a>` has padding of %1, and 100 - 2(to make up for the added height from padding) = 98% height of `<div>`. Since I want the entire picture to be clickable as a link, I nest the `<img>` in the `<a>` element with 100% height and width to fit right in. So I'm thinking at this point, I should see a picture of a dog that *at least* fits in vertically. However I get this:

https://gyazo.com/0b36f8c7efa70d7dc2b6155c821e1b1e

As you can see, the padding is correct, the width is, but the height is not. It extends by twice the padding of `<a>`. I tried also subtracting twice the padding from the height yet it makes a very small difference. It's still outside.

```css
div#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: black;
  color: limegreen;
}
a#homeiconlink {
  width: 13%;
  height: 98%;
  padding: 1%;
  float: left;
}
img#homeicon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
h2#title {
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}
div#sidebar {
  width: 15%;
  height: 60vh;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
a.sidebar:hover {
  background-color: limegreen;
  color: white;
}
a.sidebar {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  color: limegreen;
  padding: 2.5%;
}
div#contentspace {
  width: 85%;
  height: 60vh;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: limegreen;
  color: white;
  float: left;
}
div#content {
  padding: 2.5%;
}
div#footerspace {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
}
footer {
  padding: 2.5%;
  clear: both;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  color: limegreen;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
div#testedwith {
  font-style: italic;
  color: lightgray;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <a href="home.html" id="homeiconlink">
    <img src="dog.png" alt="logo" id="homeicon">
  </a>
  <h2 id="title">
        Adopt a dog or cat Foundation
       </h2>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
  <a class="sidebar" href="home.html">Home page</a>
  <a class="sidebar" href="browse.html">Browse available pets</a>
  <a class="sidebar" href="find.html">Find a dog/cat</a>
  <a class="sidebar" href="dogcare.html">Dog Care</a>
  <a class="sidebar" href="catcare.html">Cat Care</a>
  <a class="sidebar" href="giveaway.html">Have a pet to give away</a>
  <a class="sidebar" href="contact.html">Contact us</a>
</div>
<div id="contentspace">
  <div id="content">
    <h2>
         Welcome!
        </h2>
    <br>
    <p>
      At Adopt a dog or cat foundation (TM), we strive to save as many endangered dogs and cats lives as possible from the animal pound. We invite all who are loving towards animals to adopt and care for a dog or cat of your choice from somebody who can no
      longer give them the care they deserve. We strive to maintain a good community, and have a good reputation for that. Any dog or cat you adopt will most certainly be a good companion and are well trained and disease free. Thank you for helping us
      shape the world into a more hospitable one!
      <br>
      <br>-AADOCF
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footerspace">
  <footer>
    <a href="disclaimer.html">View disclaimer</a>
    <div id="testedwith">tested with Google Chrome</div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS, add `box-sizing: border-box;` `a#homeiconlink {...}`.

By default, when you specify a height, it does not take margins, padding, or borders into account.  Specifying border-box changes this so that the height you specify is total height.  More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: could you explain what was going on in more detail? step by step that lead to this output for future reference

Comment: This happens because the default (content-box) box-model presumes that when you specify a width or height of, say 20px, what you mean is 'I want the content inside of this element to have 20px of vertical space'.  What you probably meant was 'I want this element to be 20px high', this is what 'box-sizing: border-box' does.  The links I provided explain this better, I recommend checking them out.

Comment: I encountered the same problem again. All I changed was height to min-height instead for flexibility.[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obasbjes/6/). That's essentially what i need it to look like but the dog picture overlaps again. When I resize the window horizontally the dog also does which is correct, but also increases vertically which i don't want.

Comment: `height: 100%` on `a#home_icon_link` needs `div#top` to have a height attribute set.  I've updated your fiddle here:https://jsfiddle.net/obasbjes/8/.  Notice that the height can even be lower than the min-height and it still works.